# Count occurrence of each value based on key in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

So for example if I have

```
key1   john
key1   mike
key1   john
key1   rachel
key2   adam
key2   adam
key2   emily 
key2   adam
key2   George

etc
```

I want it so that I get

```
key1 : 2 john
       1 mike
       1 rachel

key2: 3 adam
      1 emily
      1 George
```

Maybe a formula or create  a pivot table?

Comment: Pivot table would be quickest and easiest.  If you want a formula, look into the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Comment: I'm new to excel, but when I create a pivot table and drag the names to the "values" box, I get the total number, not the numbers for each name

Comment: You need to drag Name column to both the rows and the values.

Comment: I did. Under 'Row Labels" I have the keys, and under "values" I have the names. It's still only showing Key1: 4, key2:5

Comment: Under Rows you need both Keys ***AND*** Name,  Then in Values you want Names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Pivot Table:

Under Rows you need both Keys ***AND*** Name,  Then in Values you want Names.

[image]